# Evaluating $\int_0^L\int_0^L \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-a^2}{2xy}\right)xy~dx~dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral to evaluate.

> $$\displaystyle\int\int_{x,y\in\Omega}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-a^2}{2xy}\right)xy~dx~dy,$$
>   where $0\le a\le L$ and $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in (0,L]\times(0,L]: |x-y|<a, 
> (x+y)>a\}$.

I used the transformation of variable as below: $$\begin{align}x&=\frac{a\sin(\theta+\phi)}{\sin \theta},\\
\\
y&=\frac{a\sin\phi}{\sin \theta}.\end{align}$$ It seems that the integral can be evaluated by this technique but I'm not sure because the calculations are getting quite messy. I was wondering is there any better method to find it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When $(x,y)$ is close to $(0,0)$ (and positive), the expression in brackets will be less than $-1$, so the integrand isn't even defined in the whole region of integration (if $\cos^{-1}$ means $\arccos$).

Comment: Yes @HansLundmark, that is something I also observed recently. I am making suitable changes in the question.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Out of curiosity, where did you encounter this integral?

Comment: This integral came in connection to a problem in random graphs. Basically, I was considering the scenario where each node is selected uniformly over a circular region of radius $L$ and each node has some radius $R<L$ within which it checks for its neighbors. So the problem was to find out the distribution of the entries in the adjacency matrix of the graph. BTW, the graph is considered undirected.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Ah, thanks. I feel much better about this integral now that I have a geometric interpretation.

Comment: @ Samrat Mukhopadhyay:
The condition $|x-y|<a$ is not sufficient to have $-1<\frac{x^2+y^2-a^2}{2xy}<1$.
For exemple with $x=0$ and $y=a/2$ we have $|x-y|<a$ and $\frac{x^2+y^2-a^2}{2xy}=-infinity$. So, with the present wording of the question, the integration is not possible.

Comment: Ok, I am editing the question.

Answer (score 5):

The integration domain is separated in four parts (figure below). The analytical result is obtained for parts (1) and (2) where the calculus is more difficult : result fonction of two paraleters $(a, L)$. The parts 3 and 4 are simpler : one parameter only $(a)$. It is solved with the same method.

[image]

Comment: I think what you intended in the second line is $$ \Phi = \{ (X, Y) \in [0, \lambda]^{2} : |X - Y| < 1 \text{ and } X + Y > 1 \}. $$

Comment: Also, $I_{1}$ seems to be \begin{align*} I_{1} &= \textstyle \frac{a^{4}}{32} \Bigg\{ 4\lambda^{4}\cos^{-1}\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2\lambda^{2}} \right) - 8\lambda^{2} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\lambda^{2} - 1}} \right) \\ & \textstyle \qquad \qquad - (2\lambda^{2} + 1)\sqrt{4\lambda^{2} - 1} + \boxed{ 4\pi (\lambda^{2} - 1) } + 3\sqrt{3} \Bigg\}. \end{align*} Of course, it is good to notice that $\cos^{-1}\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2\lambda^{2}} \right) = 2\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\lambda^{2} - 1}} \right)$, so we can simplify slightly further.

Comment: Okay, I checked every detail of your calculation, and everything else was okay. So +1 upvote! I admire your grit to face and defeat all these daunting stuffs.

Comment: Its a very good solution indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd much rather keep the integration domain square.

My suggestion is to take the derivative over parameter $a$. This makes the integral much more manageable. Arccos is gone, the square root simplifies and the $xy$ vanishes. That integral should be easier to evaluate. Then, integrate in $a$ to retrieve the original answer.

The initial value at $a=0$ still has to be integrated by hand though.

EDIT:

$$F(a)=\iint \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-a^2}{2xy}\right)xy{\,\rm d}x{\,\rm d}y$$
Derivative with respect to $a$:
$$F'(a)=\iint \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-a^2}{2xy}\right)^2}}\left(\frac{-a}{xy}\right)xy{\,\rm d}x{\,\rm d}y$$
$$F'(a)=a\iint \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{4x^2y^2-\left(x^2+y^2-a^2\right)^2}{(2xy)^2}}}{\,\rm d}x{\,\rm d}y$$
$$F'(a)=a\iint \frac{2xy}{\sqrt{2a^2(x^2+y^2)-a^4-(x^2-y^2)^2}}{\,\rm d}x{\,\rm d}y$$
This may be easier to integrate. At least once, it can be done almost trivially ($u=x^2$). Or, you could use $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=x^2-y^2$, which sets the integration domain to the diagonal square bound by $u+v=2L$, $u-v=2L$, $u+v=0$, $u-v=0$ which you could cut in two for symmetry. That's not much better, but at least less writing.

$$F'(a)=a\left(\int_0^{L}\int_0^{u}+\int_L^{2L}\int_0^{2L-u}\right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2a^2u-a^4-v^2}}{\,\rm d}v{\,\rm d}u$$

Note that this is just a suggestion - the second integation is still horrible and may not yield results. I don't have Mathematica with me so I'm not checking now.

If you manage to evaluate the integral now, you just integrate again:

$$F(a)=F(0)+\int_0^a F(t){\,\rm d}t$$

Comment: I cannot change the integration domain. Can you explain your answer showing the mathematical steps that you suggest? This will make the answer clearer.

Comment: Though your suggestion is good, you can see why I did not go through this approach. To evaluate this new integral itself is a difficult task and it is better to think about something else to solve the original integral.